# Fastest way to remove same indices from each row in 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for the fastest way (preferably with numpy) to delete a list of indices in each row of a 2D array. As an example:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],  
           [4,5,6,7,8],
           [7,8,9,10,11]]
indices_to_delete = [2,3]
```

And now the goal is to delete these indices form each row, to get:

```
result = [[1,2,5],  
         [4,5,8],
         [7,8,11]]
```

My current approach would be to do this separately for each row using:

```
result = []
for row in array:
    result.append(np.delete(row, indices_to_delete))
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Golden rule of `np.delete`: never call it in an iterative loop. It create a new copy of the array so the execution is then quadratic (`O(n m)` where `n` is the size of the array and `m` is the number of iteration). Does the order matters? If so, there are much faster methods running in (quasi-)linear time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.delete` along different axis:

```
>>> np.delete(matrix, indices_to_delete, axis=1)
array([[ 1,  2,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  8],
       [ 7,  8, 11]])
```